# How to search through data in file with certain condition

Tags: python, cgi

I have an cgi script in python which makes the search operation in a form. A form has FirstName, lastname, age and gender.

Now if the user enter Age and click on male it should display the male candidate not the femal candiadate with specified age in the field entered.

What condition am i supposed to write

Suppose theres data like

```
john duck 25 male
sashi tharoor 34 male
jacque kalis 25 male
amanda seyfried 25 female
```

if the user enter Age as "25" and selects the "male" in the form, it should display the jacque and john details only

```
        if Fname.lower() == temp[0]:
            found = True

        if Lname.lower() == temp[1]:
            found = True

        #if Age and Age == temp[2]:
            #found = True

        #if Gender and Gender == temp[3] :
            #found = True

        if Age == temp[2] and Gender == temp[3]:
            found = True
```

If I write like this, than while gender button is clicked on the form. it will display nothing

Comment: This question is nearly the same as your other [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699621/entering-two-field-data-and-making-a-search-if-satisfies-in-cgi-script-of-python) so I add this link here for reference

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
  line = f.read().split('\n')
  sex = 'male'
  age = '25'
  for l in line:
    tmp = l.split(' ')
    if sex == tmp[3] and age == tmp[2]:
      print tmp[0], tmp[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Test this with `'keyword' in 'text'`

For Example:

```
line = 'john duck 25 male'

'john' in line
> True

'john' and 'duck' in line
> True

'john' and 'female' in line
> False
```

To check if all entered values are valid you can do something like that

```
#genderEntered should be True if something was entered and False otherwise
if genderEntered == True:
    genderCorrect = gender in line

#do this for all fields

#all correct?
if genderCorrect and nameCorrect:
    #all values are correct
else:
    #at least one was not correct
```

Comment: just combine this with the Answer from @Naster and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

```
if Fname == Fsearch and Lname == Lsearch and Age == Asearch and Gender == Gsearch:
    found = True
```